# Word suggestions make EditText lose focus

Tags: android, focus, textinput, autosuggest

I have a ListView with items that contain an ImageView and an EditText. When I touch EditText, it gets focus, virtual keyboard appears and when suggestions appear above the keyboard, EditText loses focus (and suggestions disappear).

This happens on Android 2.3 (emulator and HTC Hero), and was reported on another non-2.3 device (probably Galaxy S with 2.2). HTC Hero with 2.2 and 2.1 roms don't have this problem...

Any ideas how to get rid of such behavior?

**EDIT:**

If I override onSizeChanged of ListView without calling super.onSizeChanged, focus is not lost (but a lot of other bugs is introduced...)

Answer (score 11):

https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/android-developers/ciMrAhW2P7M will solve it.  Solution copied here...

You need to make a change in your AndroidManifest.xml
Add  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to the activity holding the listview.
This will solve your problem.

```
    <activity android:name=".EditTextListView"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Comment: Tried it, but still nothing - whenever suggestions appear, edittext loses focus, and suggestions disappears...

Comment: Plus one as well.  Panning is not the nicest looking UI but it definitely solves the problem for me.  The lost of focus is the direct result of screen resize changes and redraw of items in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can disable suggestions by setting TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS

Comment: Well, that would be the last option. I wouldn't like to forbid features that users like...