# Adjust pan|adjust resize doen't seem to work on JellyBean 4.2.2-4.1.2

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a `ListView` with `EditTexts` as items.

I have tried setting both the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and `"adjustResize"`
flags in the manifest, I have also tried adding "alwaysvisible" flag and it didn't help either.

But when the keyboard hovers over the text and I start typing the edit text box is no loner visible, it only pops up the first time it gains focus.

Edit:
I have tested it on 4.3 and it worked as it supposed to work, the edittext was visible all the time, but on 4.2.1/4.2.2 it doesn't work.

Comment: Check out this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570401/1560797 . It just helped me, I had the same problem on a S2

Answer (score 7):

on some specific vendors android firmwares, settings `android:windowSoftInputMode` for `Activity` tag in Manifest won't work...

possible workaround can be setting it directly from the java code, inside the `onCreate()` method, after setting the content view:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

it's a long shot, but for me it worked in some cases...

Comment: didn't help, I used a scrollview instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. Solved it in this way:
When user clicks an EditText, I start a timer which continuously keeps the list item visible and focused. It runs for 1.5 seconds after each click.
I have a Runnable which posts itself to a handler periodically.

- Checks if the desired list item is currently visible (scrolled to the
  visible part of list).
- If it's not visible, scrolls the list to it
  (ListView.setSelectedItem(int position)).
- If it's visible, focuses
  the EditText that belongs to the list item (View.requestFocus()).

VERY ugly solution, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the android default value by not setting `android:windowSoftInputMode` or set it to `android:windowSoftInputMode:stateUnspecified`. Android will choose an appropriate state if there is no one defined in your theme. I had the same problem and this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was I have specified on my style for values-v19

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
```

which won't allow the window to resize. So either change it to `true` or within the layout you want to resize add this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" //this line!
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

On your `AndroidManifest.xml`, try to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the activity holding the listview.

Comment: thats what i'm trying to solve, why it doesn't work with adjustPan or adjustResize.

Comment: ok, try to add yourEditText.requestFocusFromTouch() on your getView()  mothode (ListAdapter)

Comment: then, maybe you have to follow this answer, "It sounds like ListViews aren't able to handle EditTexts well. I've done some research and the consensus seems to be "don't do that." So what I've resorted to is creating a simple layout file which is a ScrollView with a LinearLayout inside. In my onCreate method, I inflate the View I was using for my list item and add it to the LinearLayout. I'm also adding the View to an ArrayList so I can save the data in each View later on"  @Andrew